# How change the PATH variable enviroment of apache

Tags: php, apache-2.2

In my `phpinfo()`, in the section `Apache Environment`, i want change the value of the variable `PATH`. This is possible ?

EDIT 1:

I try `SetEnv PATH /mypath` in `httpd.conf` on a centos server, restart service and verify the change i see again a `phpinfo()`, and not change.

EDIT 2:

I edit the `/etc/profile` and add the PATH variable for all linux users,( but i cant restart the entire server for apply this change).

Comment: Did you restart Apache after making the change?  How are you testing whether or not it works?  Is it appropriate to just edit the `PATH` variable in the `.profile` file of the user that runs Apache?

Comment: edit, i restart the apache service and see the phpinfo() no has changes.

Comment: What output does `var_dump($_ENV['PATH'], $_SERVER['PATH'], getenv('PATH');` show?

Comment: the answer of jpic resolve my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [putenv()](http://php.net/putenv), example adding "/foo":

```
php > putenv('PATH=' . getenv('PATH')); print_r(getenv('PATH'));
/home/jpic/env/bin:/home/jpic/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin
php > putenv('PATH=' . getenv('PATH') . ':' . '/foo'); print_r(getenv('PATH'));
/home/jpic/env/bin:/home/jpic/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/foo
```