# Change apache (PHP) $PATH environment variable on CentOS with cPanel

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos, php, environment-variables

I need to add a path to $PATH environment variable for PHP scripts on CentOS linux server with cPanel Pro 1.0 and Apache 2.2.27.

For Ubuntu or SuSE it just means adding the row `export PATH=$PATH:/path` to `/etc/sysconfig/apache2`, but this file is missing in sysconfig on CentOS with cPanel (and, of course, script `/etc/init.d/httpd` is not looking for it). Is it anywhere else (as that would be the solution)?

The answer published [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/426978/how-change-the-path-variable-enviroment-of-apache) uses PHP itself to change PATH variable, but I'd like to use more robust solution on the Apache level... Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: It is important to mention how are you running PHP, is it suPHP, or mod_php?

Comment: The default installation, suPHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually was combination of 3 things:

1. Installation must be mod_php
2. Then the config file on CentOS with cPanel is `/usr/local/apache/bin/envvars`; and usual `export PATH=$PATH:/path` works just fine here
3. You need to stop/start httpd service, simple restart will not change the environmental variables

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3):

Edit `/opt/suphp/etc/suphp.conf` and set `env_path` to the path string that you want.

Comment: Invalid command 'env_path'...

Comment: What if I change Apache to mod_php? Would that help? It is VPS with only one website, so it is actually even logical choice...

Comment: It is not. suPHP has many advantages over mod_php. Maybe update the suPHP version? It should definitely support that command, see [here](http://www.suphp.org/DocumentationView.html?file=suphp.conf-example).